java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Eclipse Collection framework maven install
I'm trying to build Eclipse collection framework locally but after cloning git repo and running mvn install -DskipTests=true I'm getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException exception when maven tries to build Eclipse Collections OSGi Bundle
Environment:
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 17.0.8.1, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk17.0.8_8
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Pom.xml
Terminal output after running mvn install -DskipTests=true:
00:02:09:915 [INFO] Building Eclipse Collections OSGi Bundle 12.0.0-SNAPSHOT         [15/15]
00:02:09:915 [INFO]   from p2-repository\org.eclipse.collections\pom.xml
00:02:09:915 [INFO] -----------------------[ eclipse-bundle-recipe ]------------------------
00:02:09:937 [WARNING] Parameter 'jgit.dirtyWorkingTree' is unknown for plugin 'tycho-packaging-plugin:1.7.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier)'
00:02:09:937 [WARNING] Parameter 'jgit.dirtyWorkingTree' is unknown for plugin 'tycho-packaging-plugin:1.7.0:validate-version (default-validate-version)'
00:02:10:010 [INFO]
00:02:10:010 [INFO] --- tycho-packaging:1.7.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) @ org.eclipse.collections ---
00:02:12:363 [INFO] The project's OSGi version is 12.0.0.v20230828-1226
00:02:12:366 [INFO]
00:02:12:366 [INFO] --- tycho-packaging:1.7.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) @ org.eclipse.collections ---
00:02:12:371 [INFO]
00:02:12:371 [INFO] --- enforcer:3.4.1:enforce (enforce) @ org.eclipse.collections ---
00:02:12:376 [INFO] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.DependencyConvergence passed
00:02:12:382 [INFO] Rule 3: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.RequirePluginVersions passed
00:02:12:382 [INFO]
00:02:12:382 [INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ org.eclipse.collections ---
00:02:12:528 [INFO] Copying 2 resources from src\main\resources to target\classes
00:02:12:541 [INFO]
00:02:12:541 [INFO] --- compiler:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) @ org.eclipse.collections ---
00:02:12:743 [INFO] No sources to compile
00:02:12:743 [INFO]
00:02:12:743 [INFO] --- ebr:1.3.0:bundle (default-bundle) @ org.eclipse.collections ---
00:02:12:818 [INFO] Gathering dependencies
00:02:12:857 [INFO] Configured Artifact: org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections:12.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
00:02:12:894 [INFO] Configured Artifact: org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections-api:12.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
00:02:12:894 [INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\Saurabh Daware\Desktop\practice\eclipse-collections\eclipse-collections\target\eclipse-collections-12.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Saurabh Daware\Desktop\practice\eclipse-collections\p2-repository\org.eclipse.collections\target\dependency-bin with includes "**/*" and excludes "META-INF/maven/**/*.*"
00:02:39:891 [INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\Saurabh Daware\Desktop\practice\eclipse-collections\eclipse-collections-api\target\eclipse-collections-api-12.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Saurabh Daware\Desktop\practice\eclipse-collections\p2-repository\org.eclipse.collections\target\dependency-bin with includes "**/*" and excludes "META-INF/maven/**/*.*"
00:02:50:447 [INFO] Merging collected dependencies
00:02:51:248 [INFO] Copying 5681 resources from target\dependency-bin to target\classes
00:03:08:044 [INFO] Generating OSGi MANIFEST.MF
00:03:08:297 [ERROR] An internal error occurred
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.TreeMap.callMappingFunctionWithCheck (TreeMap.java:750)
    at java.util.TreeMap.computeIfAbsent (TreeMap.java:604)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.putResource (Jar.java:288)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar$1.visitFile (Jar.java:202)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar$1.visitFile (Jar.java:177)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree (Files.java:2811)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.buildFromDirectory (Jar.java:176)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init> (Jar.java:119)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init> (Jar.java:172)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.getOSGiBuilder (BundlePlugin.java:604)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.getAnalyzer (ManifestPlugin.java:285)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute (ManifestPlugin.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.buildBundle (BundleMojo.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.execute (BundleMojo.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
00:03:08:328 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Reactor Summary for Eclipse Collections Parent Project 12.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
00:03:08:330 [INFO]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Parent Project ................. SUCCESS [  2.392 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Code Generator ................. SUCCESS [ 10.457 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Code Generator Maven Plugin .... SUCCESS [  7.596 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections API ............................ SUCCESS [ 51.913 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Main Library ................... SUCCESS [03:01 min]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Test Utilities ................. SUCCESS [  8.027 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Fork Join Utilities ............ SUCCESS [  7.432 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Unit Test Suite ................ SUCCESS [04:00 min]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Serialization Test Suite ....... SUCCESS [ 17.878 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections JCStress Test Suite ............ SUCCESS [  8.749 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Test Trait JUnit Runner ........ SUCCESS [  1.631 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Java 8 Unit Test Suite ......... SUCCESS [ 25.000 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections Test Coverage Aggregation ...... SUCCESS [ 44.075 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections p2 Repository Build ............ SUCCESS [  1.716 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] Eclipse Collections OSGi Bundle .................... FAILURE [ 58.413 s]
00:03:08:330 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:03:08:338 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
00:03:08:338 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:03:08:339 [INFO] Total time:  11:10 min
00:03:08:339 [INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-06T00:03:08+05:30
00:03:08:339 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:03:08:342 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.ebr:ebr-maven-plugin:1.3.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project org.eclipse.collections: Error generating Bundle manifest: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin: ConcurrentModificationException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.ebr:ebr-maven-plugin:1.3.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project org.eclipse.collections: Error generating Bundle manifest: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error generating Bundle manifest: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.buildBundle (BundleMojo.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.execute (BundleMojo.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute (ManifestPlugin.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.buildBundle (BundleMojo.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.execute (BundleMojo.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.TreeMap.callMappingFunctionWithCheck (TreeMap.java:750)
    at java.util.TreeMap.computeIfAbsent (TreeMap.java:604)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.putResource (Jar.java:288)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar$1.visitFile (Jar.java:202)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar$1.visitFile (Jar.java:177)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree (Files.java:2811)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.buildFromDirectory (Jar.java:176)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init> (Jar.java:119)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init> (Jar.java:172)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.getOSGiBuilder (BundlePlugin.java:604)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.getAnalyzer (ManifestPlugin.java:285)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute (ManifestPlugin.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.buildBundle (BundleMojo.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.ebr.maven.BundleMojo.execute (BundleMojo.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)


Why don't you use the existing dependencies instead of building it locally?

I'm trying to contribute to Eclipse collection framework open source project.

Maybe a bug in the snapshot version. You could try to clone a stable version and see if that builds.

I'm not sure which (Eclipse Collections OSGi??) snapshot version you are referring to.

You cloned the master branch which seems to be where development of version 12 SNAPSHOT is happening. Maybe is unstable. If you checkout a tag of the last release, does it build? If a release doesn't build probably it is something in your environment.

I checked out to last major release 11.1.0 got same output.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
